# Converting a string representation of a json/dict to something usable with python request

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests

I finally had to give up and ask for help. I am retrieving a document (with requests) that has a json type of format (but is not well formatted - no double quotes) and trying to extract the data as a normal dict. Here is what I have: this works and will get you the output from which I am trying to extract the data.

```
def test():
    url = "http://www.sgx.com/JsonRead/JsonstData"
    payload = {}
    payload['qryId'] = 'RSTIc'
    payload['timeout'] = 60
    header = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Linux i686; Trident/2.0)', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}
    req = requests.get(url, headers = header, params = payload)
    print(req.url)
    prelim = req.content.decode('utf-8')
    print(type(prelim))
    print(prelim)

test()
```

What I would like to have after that is: (assuming a properly functioning dict)

```
for stock in prelim['items']:
    print(stock['N'])
```

Which should give me a list of all the stocks names.

I have tried most json functions: prelim.json(), loads., load., dump., dumps., parse. None seems to work because the data is not formatted properly. I also tried ast.literal_eval() without success. I tried some examples on Stack Overflow to convert that string in a proper dict but no luck. I don't seem to be able to convert that string to make it behave as a proper dictionary. If you can point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Good samaritains have asked for an example of the data. The data coming from the above request is a bit longer but I removed a few 'items' so people can see the general look of the retrieved data.

> {}&& {identifier:'ID', label:'As at 19-03-2018 8:38 AM',items:[{ID:0,N:'AscendasReit',SIP:'',NC:'A17U',R:'',I:'',M:'',LT:0,C:0,VL:97.600,BV:485.300,B:'2.670',S:'2.670',SV:1009.100,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:259811.200,SC:'9',PV:2.660,P:0,P_:'X',V_:''},
>   {ID:1,N:'CapitaComTrust',SIP:'',NC:'C61U',R:'',I:'',M:'',LT:0,C:0,VL:126.349,BV:1467.300,B:'1.800',S:'1.800',SV:620.900,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:228691.690,SC:'9',PV:1.810,P:0,P_:'X',V_:''},
>   {ID:2,N:'CapitaLand',SIP:'',NC:'C31',R:'',I:'',M:'',LT:0,C:0,VL:78.000,BV:184.900,B:'3.670',S:'3.670',SV:372.900,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:286026.000,SC:'9',PV:3.660,P:0,P_:'X',V_:''},
>   {ID:28,N:'Wilmar Intl',SIP:'',NC:'F34',R:'CD',I:'',M:'',LT:0,C:0,VL:0.000,BV:32.000,B:'3.210',S:'3.210',SV:73.100,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:0.000,SC:'2',PV:3.220,P:0,P_:'',V_:''},
>   {ID:29,N:'YZJ Shipbldg SGD',SIP:'',NC:'BS6',R:'',I:'',M:'',LT:0,C:0,VL:0.000,BV:349.500,B:'1.330',S:'1.330',SV:417.700,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:0.000,SC:'2',PV:1.340,P:0,P_:'',V_:''}]}

Following the recent commentaries, I know I could do this:

```
def test2():
    my_text = "{}&& {identifier:'ID', label:'As at 19-03-2018 8:38 AM',items:[{ID:0,N:'AscendasReit',SIP:'',NC:'A17U',R:'',I:'',M:'',LT:0,C:0,VL:97.600,BV:485.300,B:'2.670',S:'2.670',SV:1009.100,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:259811.200,SC:'9',PV:2.660,P:0,P_:'X',V_:''}, {ID:1,N:'CapitaComTrust',SIP:'',NC:'C61U',R:'',I:'',M:'',LT:0,C:0,VL:126.349,BV:1467.300,B:'1.800',S:'1.800',SV:620.900,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:228691.690,SC:'9',PV:1.810,P:0,P_:'X',V_:''}, {ID:2,N:'CapitaLand',SIP:'',NC:'C31',R:'',I:'',M:'',LT:0,C:0,VL:78.000,BV:184.900,B:'3.670',S:'3.670',SV:372.900,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:286026.000,SC:'9',PV:3.660,P:0,P_:'X',V_:''}, {ID:28,N:'Wilmar Intl',SIP:'',NC:'F34',R:'CD',I:'',M:'',LT:0,C:0,VL:0.000,BV:32.000,B:'3.210',S:'3.210',SV:73.100,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:0.000,SC:'2',PV:3.220,P:0,P_:'',V_:''}, {ID:29,N:'YZJ Shipbldg SGD',SIP:'',NC:'BS6',R:'',I:'',M:'',LT:0,C:0,VL:0.000,BV:349.500,B:'1.330',S:'1.330',SV:417.700,O:0,H:0,L:0,V:0.000,SC:'2',PV:1.340,P:0,P_:'',V_:''}]}"
    prelim = my_text.split("items:[")[1].replace("}]}", "}")
    temp_list = prelim.split(", ")
    end_list = []
    main_dict = {}
    for tok1 in temp_list:
        temp_dict = {}
        temp = tok1.replace("{","").replace("}","").split(",")
        for tok2 in temp:            
            my_key = tok2.split(":")[0]
            my_value = tok2.split(":")[1].replace("'","")
            temp_dict[my_key] = my_value
        end_list.append(temp_dict)    
    main_dict['items'] = end_list
    for stock in main_dict['items']:
        print(stock['N'])

test2()
```

Which is the desired result. I am just asking, if there is an easier (more elegant/pythonic) way of doing this.

Comment: Please include an example of your data, specifically a "malformed" segment.

Comment: You should show what the data looks like. That's more important than how you got it. The code that retrieves the data is completely irrelevant to the actual question.

Comment: o/p from http://www.sgx.com/JsonRead/JsonstData is not in JSON format. Its in string. So you need manually convert into json parsable text and do `json.loads(converted_text)`

Comment: Check my answer. let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string to JSON convertible text first then use `json.loads` to get dictionary

`prelim` is not in JSON format and values are not surrounded by `"`

- Remove `'{}&& '`
- Surround properties with `"`
- Apply `json.loads(new_text)` to get the dictionary representation

i.e

```
import requests, json
#replace tuples 
reps = (('identifier:', '"identifier":'),
        ('label:', '"label":'),
        ('items:', '"items":'),
        ('NC:', '"NC":'),
        ('ID:', '"ID":'),
        ('N:', '"N":'),
        ('SIP:', '"SIP":'),
        ('SC:', '"SC":'),
        ('R:', '"R":'),
        ('I:', '"I":'),
        ('M:', '"M":'),
        ('LT:', '"LT":'),
        ('C:', '"C":'),
        ('VL:', '"VL":'),
        ('BV:', '"BV":'),
        ('BL:', '"BL":'),
        ('B:', '"B":'),
        ('S:', '"S":'),
        ('SV:', '"SV":'),
        ('O:', '"O":'),
        ('H:', '"H":'),
        ('L:', '"L":'),
        ('PV:', '"PV":'),
        ('V:', '"V":'),
        ('P_:', '"P_":'),
        ('P:', '"P":'),
        ('V_:', '"V_":'))

#getting rid of invalid json text
prelim = prelim.replace('{}&& ', '')

#replacing single quotes with double quotes
prelim = prelim.replace("'", "\"")

print(prelim)
#reduce to get all replacements
dict_text = fn.reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), reps, prelim)
dic = json.loads(dict_text)
print(dic)
```

**get Items:**

```
for x in dic['items']:
    print(x['N'])
```

**Output:**

```
2ndChance W200123
3Cnergy
3Cnergy W200528
800 Super
8Telecom^
A-Smart
A-Sonic Aero^
AA
....
```